# Circular navigator for div slider

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div slider and sliders div are coming dynamic with JSON file, i want to add circle navigator whenever my JSON file is getting updated or adding a new div, below is the sample code.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sliders">
        <div class="set"><img src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/232/0/b/random_surfer_panoramic_by_jaydoncabe-d6fin5d.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="set"><img src="http://www.theultimatefinish.co.uk/Images/Rupes-Big-Foot-Random-Orbital-System.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="set"><img src="http://0.media.dorkly.cvcdn.com/93/93/7ad889644c2e4a189c20656c6077683f.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="set"><img src="http://cdn-www.cracked.com/articleimages/dan/coincidences/corsica.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="set"><img src="http://i299.photobucket.com/albums/mm312/AvatarSchool/DesignMagazine/CountdownLayouts/image18.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="next">Next</div>
        <div class="circles">
            <a href="#" class="active"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="prev">Prev</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript? If possible, show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: i am not any idea how to start here. http://jsfiddle.net/jBj2Y/

Comment: kindly fill in the JavaScript part also in your fiddle. Its ok with HTML and CSS